# Why is the time limit exceeding in reversing the linked list?

Tags: python, time, linked-list, reverse, reversing

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.

 class ListNode:

     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
         self.val = val
         self.next = next

class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        prev=ListNode(-1,head)
        curr=head
        dummy=head
        while dummy.next:
            curr.next=prev
            prev=dummy
            dummy=dummy.next
            curr=dummy
        return prev
```

I created three nodes, I used the prev and curr node for reversing and the dummy node for traversing ahead in the original linked list but I am getting time limit exceeded. I would like to know my logical error in this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- In the loop you modify the node's `next` attribute **before** saving the original `next` reference. So once that is done, you have lost all possibility to move forward in list, and `dummy=dummy.next` will now walk **back** since at the start of the iteration, `dummy` was equal to `curr`.
- It is undesired to create a new node with value. Your code would link back to it in the first iteration of the loop. And because of the first problem, `dummy` becomes `prev`, which has a `next` reference to where you came from, creating an infinite loop. Instead of this -1 Node, just initialise `prev` as `None`.
- The `while` condition is wrong. The loop should continue until you reach the very last node, so when `curr` is `None`.
- Not a major issue, but why call that node reference `dummy`? There is nothing dummy about it. Use a name that describes what it references, for instance `nextNode` or `nxt` for short.

Correction:

```
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head):
        prev=None  # Don't create a new node
        curr=head
        while curr:  # Continue until the *last* node
            nxt=curr.next  # Save the next reference
            curr.next=prev
            prev=curr
            curr=nxt  # ... so you can move ahead
        return prev
```